# What is OLK15message files and how to recover it?

Tags: macos, email, ms-office, recovery

Can anyone explain to me what is an OLK15message file, what it has to do with Outlook 2016 for mac? Actually, my outlook mac database got corrupted and someone told me that Outlook Mac stores its database in OLK15 message files. Is that so? If yes then how can I recover OLK15message files in order to restore my Outlook 2016 for Mac?

Please keep the explanation basic as I am not at aware of complex technological terms. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from OLM files, Mac Outlook creates temporary files in the backend called as OLK file. These contain data exclusively related to individual profiles. It is stored in the identity folder of the respective profile to which it relates. The OLK file only stores the header information of the mails data. For storing message content without attachment Mac Outlook Creates OLK14/15MSGSOURCE.

The location of OLK Files:
[user]/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Data Records/Messages Source

Its recovery is a bit risky one but here's an article that explains how to recover OLK15message files: http://olk15messagerecovery.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there is no such thing as an OLK15 message file, according to [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984224(v=office.16).aspx):

> Outlook 2016 for Mac stores messages and other items, such as calendar
>   events, contacts, tasks, and notes, as a SQLite database here:

```
/Users/username/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles
```

(I found no OLK15 files on my Mac with Office 2016. I *did* find a number of SQLite files, YMMV)

A SQLite database is a database file format that Apple and many other companies use to store application data in. A non-technical user has no chance of understanding what to do with the SQLite file even if they do manage to find a tool that will open the file.

Your best bet is to restore the folder specified above from the regular backups you make of your computer either via Time Machine or another backup program, as per the article at the link above.

If you don't have a backup you have just learned a valuable lesson, "Backups are a pain and require me to buy a backup drive." But the moment you lose data and **do not** have a backup you realize you should have shelled out the bucks and dedicated the time to doing regular backups, IMHO.

If the Outlook database is corrupt the chances of getting *anything* usable out of it is slim.

Comment: I have many `.olk15message` files in `~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Messages`

Answer (score 0):

OLK15message files are a separate backup scheme that Outlook mac used to store its database. As far as your recovery query is concerned, I don't think that it's possible to recover OLK15message files without a third party tool.

However, you can rebuild your identity folder, which will give you all your email database back in your mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "proper" recovery back into Outlook, but I've found the python script referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473923/parse-olk15message-file-in-python-on-mac) to work very nicely in rescuing my old UBF8T346G9.Office data folders containing Olk15message format emails into something I can read (no attachments though)

[UBF8T346G9.office Parser](https://github.com/glymphie/UBF8T346G9Parser)  at GitHub